# Signal processing techniques for unevenly spaced and repeated measures series

Tags: repeated-measures, signal-processing, noise, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am considering using signal processing techniques to find the minimum on a noisy 1D response line. More specifically I have a simulation that requires one parameter, but also includes randomness, and I want to adjust the parameter to fit some data. By fixing the parameter, I can have many different answers by running different simulations. The variance of the different outputs is not constant in the parameter space.

I am planning to generate random samples of the parameter, and do some filtering on the resulting error from the simulator output to the real data. But:

a) the points in the parameter space (line) may be uneven. I could do an evenly spaced grid search in the parameter values but if there is a solution where I can just sample according to the prior on the parameter it would be better.

b) there may be more than one measure for the same parameter value. I can substitute these multiple values for the same parameter value by their mean, but then I have to weight that data point more than non-average data points.

Can someone point me in some directions/literature on signal processing techniques for
a) uneven spaced data
b) multiple valued or weighted data